# How to fix font size while user zooms(CTRL+'+') in my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to keep the font size to be fixed even when the user zooms. Can I accomplish it without using javascript. Is there any html or css method to achieve it.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What about accessibility?

Comment: Trying to drive users away from your site?

Comment: So, you want to keep the user from zooming? You want to display the text at the same size, even though you know the user thinks it's too small? WHY?

Comment: It is that I am having a static page.. Most of the contents are images. But I have a copyright text in the footer.. The text is all big enough to read.. I have went through lot of websites and could not find an answer

Comment: _"The text is all big enough to read"_ - Because everybody in the world has eyesight as good as yours? That's good news.

Comment: Well let's just say for educational purpose. There should be some way.

Comment: There are ways. ⁎⁎cough⁎⁎vmin⁎⁎cough⁎⁎ Like we're gonna tell you though.

Answer (score 2):

The use case seems to make sense.

Try this, but be careful since it is only a workaround which might not be well-supported.

```
.yourText {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    }
```

Regards

Comment: Well, it worked in Dreamweaver... But yes, FF doesn't work :-(